# How can I include other downloaded packages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've found [Javaluator](http://javaluator.soft.fathzer.com/en/home/), and it looks like something I'd like to use in my java project. When I go to the downloads page, there are 2 options, maven or a zip folder containing lots of `.JAR` files. I'm very new to eclipse and java programming as a whole, and was wondering how I could sort of "Import" or include them in my project. Any help appriciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps to add externally downloaded java packages(JAR) file to an Eclipse Project.

- Right click on your project.
- Select Build Path.
- Click on Configure Build Path.
- Click on Libraries and select Add External JARs.
- Select the jar file from the required folder.
- Click and Apply and Ok.

All done.